# How do I uninstall PHP CodeSniffer on Mac OSX (10.11.6)?

Tags: php, pear, uninstallation, phpcodesniffer

I used Pear to install PHP CodeSniffer, and something went terribly wrong. It seems like most of the files weren't copied over. Perhaps I should have installed it with root privileges. It doesn't work, it's a mess, and I want to uninstall it and reinstall it, but I don't know how to uninstall it and I can't find any information about this. The Pear script is long and complicated. I tried:

pear uninstall PHP_CodeSniffer-3.2.3

It says that it's not installed.

But when I try to reinstall over the existing installation, it says I can't because it's already installed.

Comment: Does "-2" mean this is a stupid question? If so, please tell me the answer while you're passing by to click the Down arrow. Thanks.

Comment: The installation script is 178 pages long. Literally. Can't someone please tell me how to manually install and uninstall this thing? It can't truly take 178 pages. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I'm posting it despite the -1 score I got for my question - up from -2. I'm sure I'm not the only one who had this problem, and it took hours of searching to find the solution. I'm not a pear expert. I only just installed it to use PHP_CodeSniffer.

The pear uninstall command didn't work because the cache needed to be cleared. These commands worked, when logged in as root. I then reinstalled as root.

```
pear clear-cache
pear uninstall PHP_CodeSniffer
```

Comment: Time will correct mistaken opinions about this question, thank you.